# Why the internal resistance of battery is greater than internal resistance of car's accumulator?

Tags: battery-charging

It is really important for me to understand the following question.
I know that it is a basic stuff, but I think that I am still missing something.

In my opinion it is caused by the fact that the battery is not as accurate as car accumulator. 
Is there more causes of this effect?

Edit: I mean the very normal battery one of which we can buy in every single shop.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What battery?

Comment: I edited my post I mean a basic battery which we can buy in every single shop.

Comment: Are you asking "why is the internal resistance of a 9v toy battery greater than that of a 12v automobile battery?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size.

The surface area of a car's battery / accumulator is many, many times that of a AA battery. This, along with the chemistry lowers the internal resistance of the battery.

In addition, the car's battery is *designed* to have low resistance to enable it to deliver high currents for the engine starter motor.

> In my opinion it is caused by the fact that the battery is not as accurate as car accumulator.

I think there is a language problem here. Batteries are not "accurate". The output voltage is a function of the chemistry, size and design.

Comment: Is there any mathematic formula for this?

Comment: Did you search? Anyway, a formula isn't any use to you unless you're going to design batteries. For using batteries you read the manufacturers' datasheets.

Comment: OK I will try to find it.